# RMSE Landsat8 AVHRR

Tags: image, error-handling

I would like to do a spatial validation between a Landsat8 NDVI IMG and an AVHRR NDVI IMG

both IMG have the same projection, extent and pixel size

For that I would like to determine the RMSE.
However, I get the error message:

at the line:

```
error <- actual - predicted
```

this error and can not continue
Error in actual - predicted:
   non-numeric argument for binary operator

How do I have to change the code to get ahead?
here is my complete code

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rastervis)
library(rgl)
library(dplyr)

#Setze den Pfad
setwd("/home/franziska/r-Daten/RSME")

#lade beide Raster
AVHRR <- raster("AVHRR_NDVI.tif")
Landsat <- raster("Landsat_NDVI.tif")`

# diese Funktion soll den RMSE bestimmen
rmse <- function(error)
{
 sqrt(mean(error^2))
}

# diese Funktion gibt den absoluten Fehler zurück
mae <- function(error)
{
  mean(abs(error))
}

# Weiße die Raster den Variablen zu
actual <- c(Landsat)
predicted <- c(AVHRR)

# Berechne den Fehler
error <- actual - predicted

# Ausgabe der Zwischenberechnungen
rmse(error)
mae(error)


lm.D9 <- lm(Landsat ~ AVHRR)
rmse(lm.D9$residuals) # RSME
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your simplified code with some example data (this is how you should ask a question here).

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
Landsat <- raster(f, 1)
AVHRR <- raster(f, 3)

error <- Landsat - AVHRR
#You can do
#[1] 25.52578
#mae <- mean(abs(values(error)))
#mae
#[1] 15.28597
```

But the memory-safe way would be to do

```
cellStats(error, "rms")
#[1] 25.52742
cellStats(abs(error), "mean")
#[1] 15.28597
```

Note that I am returning a single "global" value, whereas your functions would return a raster --- suggesting perhaps that you want "local" error statistics. But that only makes sense if you have multi-layer raster data. In your example you do not; but see below for a local example.

So what causes your error? You do

```
#actual <- c(Landsat)
#predicted <- c(AVHRR)
#error <- actual - predicted
```

Or with our example data

```
error <- c(Landsat) - c(AVHRR)
#Error in c(Landsat) - c(AVHRR) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

This is because `c(Landsat)` creates a `list` and you cannot subtract two lists.

```
class(c(Landsat))
#[1] "list"
```

You *could* do

```
error <- c(Landsat)[[1]] - c(AVHRR)[[1]]
```

(but why would you)

If you want "local" values, you can do something like the below:

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
Landsat <- stack(f)
AVHRR <- Landsat[[3:1]]
error <- Landsat - AVHRR

mae <- mean(abs(error))
plot(mae)
```